# Trigger a segue from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, segue, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm a noob to iOS dev and I'm trying to implement a simple Facebook Connect, but when the user is logged in I want the app to change view automatically.

In my storyboard I have the `FacebookLoginViewController` that is embeded inside a NavigationController. Then I've added a segue between `FacebookLoginViewController` and `UploadViewController` (where I let the user pick an image and upload it to AWS S3).

[image]

I've check the [Facebook Sample](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBLoginCustomUISample/FBLoginCustomUISample) to inspire me.

The problem I'm facing is with the segue between `FacebookLoginViewController` and `UploadViewController`. This Segue has the following identifier: `LoginSuccessSegue`

In `AppDelegate`, when a session state change, the following method is called:
`- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error`

In this method, when the user is logged in, another method is called: `userLoggedIn`

Now, what I want to do here is trigger the Segue to perform the push transition between `FacebookLoginViewController` and `UploadViewController`. And I have to do it from the `AppDelegate` because it's here that the session state is checked.

I've tried to instantiate `FacebookLoginViewController` and call a method I've defined to trigger the segue.

In `AppDelegate.m`:

```
// Show the user the logged-in UI
- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    // Switch view to pick image
    FacebookLoginViewController *LoginController = [[FacebookLoginViewController alloc] init];
    [LoginController successLoginTransition];
}
```

In `FacebookLoginViewController.m`:

```
-(void)successLoginTransition
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccessSegue" sender:self];
}
```

But doing so I end up with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'LoginSuccessSegue''

---

**To make sure the Segue is working**, I've created a button in the `FacebookLoginViewController` that is calling the following method:

```
-(IBAction)testSegue:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccessSegue" sender:self];
}
```

And this is working.

---

I've tried to search for this error but I could find anything helpful.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and maybe how I should do to trigger this transition?

Cheers, 
Maxime

Comment: Did you actually give your segue the identifier of "LoginSuccessSegue" in storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did, I even created a button to test it and it's working. (I've updated the question with the test action of the button)

Answer (score 1):

Don't `alloc init` the `UIViewController` because you are using storyboards.

Change

```
- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    // Switch view to pick image
    FacebookLoginViewController *LoginController =
                                          [[FacebookLoginViewController alloc] init];
    [LoginController successLoginTransition];
}
```

to

```
- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    // Switch view to pick image
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" 
                                                         bundle:nil];
    FacebookLoginViewController *LoginController = 
                 [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FbLoginView"];
    [LoginController successLoginTransition];
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

You want to naviguate to the image Picker, no need to make the LoginController push a segue. you can just do it directly:

```
- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    // Switch view to pick image
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    pickImageViewController *LoginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pickImageView"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:LoginController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: it says property storyboard not found

Comment: @maxwell2022 oops its different for appdeleguate, I fixed it

Comment: One last question. Where can I find the name of the storyboard?

Comment: It looks like mine is called `Main.storyboard` but I got the following error: `Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard'`

Comment: I added an screenshot

Comment: Thanks, now I have the following error: `"Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <.../33188979-8D3F-4A0E-8434-59A32B76DE3F/uploadS3.app> (loaded)' with name 'Main_Storyboard'"`

Comment: The default name for a storyboard is Main_storyboard - unless you have changed it

Comment: then it would be `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];`

Comment: it was `Main`, I've changed it for `Main_Storyboard`. it was not working so now I've changed it to `Main_iPhone` and still not working. https://github.com/Maxwell2022/S3Upload/blob/master/uploadS3Tutorial/AppDelegate.m#L129

Comment: Thanks for the zip. Changing the storyboard to "Main" fixed it but I have another error: `Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'LoginSuccessSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.` Do I need a second navigation controller in my storyboard?

Comment: when do you get this error, when I clicked it took me to the image picker, the other button logged me in an out

Comment: I have an active Facebook session, so the AppDelegate is calling the userLoggedIn method straight when I launch the app in simulator and it crashed at this point